# C# inserting double into MySQL database with decimals producing errors

Tags: c#, mysql

My apologies if this is a question that was already asked before, but I can't seem to find anything that works for my situation.

I have this method below which inserts data into my database but for some reason when I insert the `price` value with decimals it throws an exception but if I insert it without decimals it is accepted and adds everything to the database. In other words `price = 13.55` throws an error and `price = 13` does not.
The `Price` column in the MySQL Database was declared to be GAAP Compliant with `Double(13,4)` being the DataType.

The function:

```
public int InsertPart(string partNumber, string name, string description, string price)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Instance != null)
            {
                _SqlQuery = $"INSERT INTO {_SchemaName}.part SET PartNumber = @PartNumber, Name = @Name, Description = @Description, Price = @Price";
                _MySqlCommand = new MySqlCommand(_SqlQuery, _MySqlConnection);
                _MySqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 100;

                _MySqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@PartNumber", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 15));
                _MySqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@Name", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 30));
                _MySqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@Description", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 40));
                _MySqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@Price", MySqlDbType.Double, 13));

                _MySqlCommand.Parameters["@PartNumber"].Value = partNumber;
                _MySqlCommand.Parameters["@Name"].Value = name;
                _MySqlCommand.Parameters["@Description"].Value = description;
                _MySqlCommand.Parameters["@Price"].Value = MainProgramCode.ParseDouble(price);

                _MySqlCommand.Prepare();
                int AffectedRows = _MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                _MySqlCommand.Dispose();
                return AffectedRows;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MainProgramCode.ShowError("An error occurred while attempting to add the new part to the database.\nNo changes can be done at this time!", "ERROR - Database Insertion");
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

The `MainProgramCode.ParseDouble(price)` function calls this code:

```
public static Double ParseDouble(string t)
    {
        Double.TryParse(t, NumberStyles.Currency, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out Double temp);
        return temp;
    }
```

I have tried declaring this line: `MySqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@Price", MySqlDbType.Double, 13));` in this way as well but it also gives me the same problem:

```
_MySqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@Price", MySqlDbType.Double));
_MySqlCommand.Parameters["@Price"].Precision = 13;
_MySqlCommand.Parameters["@Price"].Scale = 4;
```

I have also tried it this way but I had no luck:

```
_MySqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", MainProgramCode.ParseDouble(price));
```

Any advise or help will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

The error message that keeps on popping up:

> "Input string was not in a correct format."

> ex.StackTrace = at    System.Number.ParseDouble(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)    at    system.String.System.IConvertible.ToDouble(IFormatProvider provider)    at    System.Convert.ToDouble(Object value)    at    MySql.Data.Types.MySqlDouble.MySql.Data.Types.IMySqlValue.WriteValue(MySqlPacket packet, Boolean binary, Object val, Int32 length)    at    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter.Serialize(MySqlPacket packet, Boolean binary, MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)    at    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.PreparableStatement.Execute()    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)    at    MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()    at    MainProgramLibrary.Database.InsertPart(String partNumber, String name, String description, String price) in C:\Users\vanzy\OneDrive\Documents\Quote Swift Files\Visual Sudio Files\QuoteSwift\MainProgramLibrary\Database.cs:line 128    `

line 128 is `int AffectedRows = _MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: If your database column is a decimal, why not use `MySqlDbType.Decimal` rather than `MySqlDbType.Double`? Similarly, why not parse your string to a decimal?

Comment: @GarethD yes, MySQL allows the SET syntax with inserts that does make it look like an update hybrid.

Comment: @mjwills I have edited it and added the error. Also the `I have also tried it this way but I had no luck:` it gave me the same error. `(new MySqlParameter("@Description", MySqlDbType.Double, 40));` was a copy paste error due to `ctrl+z`-ing

Comment: @BradleyGrainger I'm assuming it's the `StackTrace` property the exception object provides. I'll add it as an edit

Comment: @mjwills Seems like it was fixed after VS2019 had an update, don't know how or why but I'll delete this question as to not waste anyone else's time further. My apologies for wasting yours

Comment: @mjwills thank you. I appreciate it.

Comment: @EttienneVanZyl are you sure you're assigning a `double` to the `MySqlParameter.Value` property? I can reproduce a problem if I write `_MySqlCommand.Parameters["@Price"].Value = "13.55";` but not `_MySqlCommand.Parameters["@Price"].Value = 13.55;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're experiencing a bug in MySql.Data that I haven't seen reported before.

I'm guessing that you're in a non-U.S.-English locale, and that `double`s aren't formatted with U.S. formatting (i.e., `.` as decimal separator).

This code in MySql.Data attempts to perform a culture-sensitive conversion, which will fail if the string contains a period, but the current culture doesn't use them: https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-net/blob/a18f0417fc6864b378444d8936722bfbd126bb0d/MySQL.Data/src/Types/MySqlDouble.cs#L66

You could:

- report the bug at bugs.mysql.com and hope for a fix in an upcoming version
- force the current thread's `CurrentCulture` to `en-US` so that culture-sensitive conversions work properly
- switch to a different MySQL ADO.NET library that doesn't have this bug, e.g., [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/) (disclaimer: lead author)